# Enforce a type at runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript, casting, variable-assignment

I have a `user` model class which looks something like this :

```
{
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
   someSwitch: boolean;
}
```

If I declare a user, the class is enforced by default and will fail at compile time :

```
fooUser : User = {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}
```

Would fail as it needs `someSwitch` to be defined (unless it would be marked as optional in the class)

How could I enforce this model to be respected at runtime without testing for each field independently as this would work just fine when running :

```
someJson = {
   firstName: string;
   lastName: string;
}

fooUser : User = someJson;
```

What I could do is simply create a constructor to `User` and assign everything mandatory in it and then create the Object when I need it but it seems weird to have to create a constructor to a simple data model, Maybe I'm just looking to far and this is the right solution.

Comment: Does this need to be done on the backend or the frontend? You can use `Proxy` but there are browser compatibility issues

Comment: @AyushGupta This needs to be done in my Angular component. I'll look into `Proxy` but it seems to be a workaround for something simple. This whole things points to me having a bad design in mind.

Comment: probably worth looking into `joi`: https://github.com/hapijs/joi

Comment: TypeScript doesn't provide any runtime type system and that is [beyond the goals of the project](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals). There are 3rd party libraries that try to tackle this, such as [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts) (I've never tried it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately there is no way to do this in js without testing for the required properties. You can do typeof(x) checks but that will only help for base types (object, string, number, boolean).

**Edit**

After some further research, I think you can actually do something like this with the [instanceof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof) operator.

> The instanceof operator tests the presence of constructor.prototype in object's prototype chain.